# Correct way to deploy laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I’m trying deploy my first laravel project on live server.

1. Should i deploy with composer.lock from local project?
2. Should i deploy with local vendor?

**What i did:**:

When i deploy without composer.lock `composer install` command not installing packages on live server. I tried upload composer.json and run `composer update` didnt work and got out of memory error. Then i removed composer.lock from .gitignore is that correct?

**What is correct way to deploy?**

Comment: You want to include both `composer.lock` and `composer.json` in your deployment, then run `composer install`. `composer update` is not what you want for a deployment - it attempts to *upgrade* all the packages, which may break your application entirely (plus it takes much, much longer to run).

Comment: Side note: `composer install` is specifically recommended in the documentation. `composer.lock` is also not in `.gitignore` by default - you (or someone else) must've added it. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you should use your local composer.lock file to make sure that the live environment uses the same package versions as local.
2. You can but usually you do `composer install` on your live environment. But if you do upload the vendor directory you don´t need `composer install` at all.

There is no "correct" way of doing your deployment. It usually depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use your local "**composer lock**" file. But laravel recommend not use local "**composer lock**", after "**composer update**" command its generate new lock file and it works fine.
2. you can use local vendor. But laravel recommend not to use local vendor file, when you run "**composer udpate**" command laravel generate vendor folder again and this process is better. Also laravel add this "**vendor**" folder to gitignore file also to avoid unnecessary files to push.